# Magento Add Condition Rule In A Custom Form in magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminform, rules

I want to add condition action in custom module admin form. How can I achieve this?

[Refer link for Magento 1.9](http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/magento-add-condition-rule-in-a-custom-form/)

Replacement of above link for Magento 2.

Comment: Which version you have tried?

Comment: Magento 2.0 or Magento 2.1 any one of them.

Comment: @Manish If one of the answers above helped you solve the problem, please feel free to mark it as a solution.

Comment: thanks but it this solution not solve my problem. I have to add many things.

Comment: @Manish Why don't you add own answer with a solution? It can help someone other.

Comment: Sure, I will quite busy right now I will add as soon as get free. Sorry for the inconvience

Comment: I have added in ui form. i have saved it in db as serialised condition. however, i am getting empty field on edit form. could you help?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190537/magento-2-sales-rules-in-custom-ui-form-is-empty-on-editing

Answer (score 14):

To add a conditional field to the default model (and further utilize it for validating purposes), you will need to create a new model (or modify the existing one) that contains these fields.

> app/code/Vendor/Rules/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Rules\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('vendor_rules')
        )->addColumn(
            'rule_id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Rule Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'name',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'Name'
        )->addColumn(
            'description',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            '64k',
            [],
            'Description'
        )->addColumn(
            'from_date',
            Table::TYPE_DATE,
            null,
            ['nullable' => true, 'default' => null],
            'From'
        )->addColumn(
            'to_date',
            Table::TYPE_DATE,
            null,
            ['nullable' => true, 'default' => null],
            'To'
        )->addColumn(
            'is_active',
            Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
            'Is Active'
        )->addColumn(
            'conditions_serialized',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            '2M',
            [],
            'Conditions Serialized'
        )->addColumn(
            'sort_order',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
            'Sort Order (Priority)'
        )->addIndex(
            $installer->getIdxName('vendor_rules', ['sort_order', 'is_active', 'to_date', 'from_date']),
            ['sort_order', 'is_active', 'to_date', 'from_date']
        )->setComment(
            'Own Rules'
        );

        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Now, we have a table with the model description and we need to complete the model itself, and include into it the appropriate resource model and collection.

The model will be called 'Rule':

> app/code/Vendor/Rules/Model/Rule.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Rules\Model;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel;

/**
 * Class Rule
 * @package Vendor\Rules\Model
 *
 * @method int|null getRuleId()
 * @method Rule setRuleId(int $id)
 */
class Rule extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Prefix of model events names
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'vendor_rules';

    /**
     * Parameter name in event
     *
     * In observe method you can use $observer->getEvent()->getRule() in this case
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventObject = 'rule';

    /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory */
    protected $condCombineFactory;

    /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory */
    protected $condProdCombineF;

    /**
     * Store already validated addresses and validation results
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $validatedAddresses = [];

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->condCombineFactory = $condCombineFactory;
        $this->condProdCombineF = $condProdCombineF;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $localeDate, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Set resource model and Id field name
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('Vendor\Rules\Model\ResourceModel\Rule');
        $this->setIdFieldName('rule_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get rule condition combine model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine
     */
    public function getConditionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condCombineFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * Get rule condition product combine model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Combine
     */
    public function getActionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condProdCombineF->create();
    }

    /**
     * Check cached validation result for specific address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Set validation result for specific address to results cache
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @param bool $validationResult
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setIsValidForAddress($address, $validationResult)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] = $validationResult;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cached validation result for specific address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @return bool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.BooleanGetMethodName)
     */
    public function getIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] : false;
    }

    /**
     * Return id for address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getAddressId($address)
    {
        if ($address instanceof Address) {
            return $address->getId();
        }
        return $address;
    }
}
```

As you can see, our model inherits from the `Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel` model that already has all the required methods.

Right in the Constructor, we'll add condition factories that allow us to work with them and create multiple methods. This should give us the understanding of how the model works.

Note that we are using the default condition models from the Magento SalesRule (`\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition`) module. If you need to expand the conditions, you can add your own clasees and/or rewrite them completely or inherit from the base available classes. In can be useful when you want to add a special condition that is not included in the default conditions. For example, **Subtotal With Discount**.

....

Next, let's switch to the interface in the admin panel. We need the Controller with a set of actions (such as Save, Add, Edit, Grid Display, Conditions reload) and a layout with blocks.

Let's start with the Controller itself. First, declare the common Controller:

> app/code/Vendor/Rules/Controller/Adminhtml/Example/Rule.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Rules\Controller\Adminhtml\Example;

abstract class Rule extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\Date
     */
    protected $dateFilter;

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Rules\Model\RuleFactory
     */
    protected $ruleFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\Date $dateFilter
     * @param \Vendor\Rules\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\Date $dateFilter,
        \Vendor\Rules\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->dateFilter = $dateFilter;
        $this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * Initiate rule
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _initRule()
    {
        $rule = $this->ruleFactory->create();
        $this->coreRegistry->register(
            'current_rule',
            $rule
        );
        $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        if (!$id && $this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id')) {
            $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id');
        }

        if ($id) {
            $this->coreRegistry->registry('current_rule')->load($id);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initiate action
     *
     * @return Rule
     */
    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('Vendor_Rules::vendor_rules')
            ->_addBreadcrumb(__('Example Rules'), __('Example Rules'));
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns result of current user permission check on resource and privilege
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_Rules::rules');
    }
}
```

Here, we need to call out our models' factory in the Constructor. That is done to make them (and some auxiliary classes, like a register and a logger) publicy available.

The `_initRule` method is responsible for the current rule initialization or creating of a new and empty one with the ability of adding it to the register.
The `_initAction()` method loads a layout and makes the modules' menu available for actions (also, it adds breadcumbs).
The `_isAllowed()` method checks if the current admin has an access to the Controller.

At the next step, we are going to add the default actions:

....

Editing:

> app/code/Vendor/Rules/Controller/Adminhtml/Example/Rule/Edit.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Rules\Controller\Adminhtml\Example\Rule;

class Edit extends \Vendor\Rules\Controller\Adminhtml\Example\Rule
{
    /**
     * Rule edit action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        /** @var \Vendor\Rules\Model\Rule $model */
        $model = $this->ruleFactory->create();

        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            if (!$model->getRuleId()) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This rule no longer exists.'));
                $this->_redirect('vendor_rules/*');
                return;
            }
        }

        // set entered data if was error when we do save
        $data = $this->_session->getPageData(true);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model->addData($data);
        }

        $model->getConditions()->setJsFormObject('rule_conditions_fieldset');

        $this->coreRegistry->register('current_rule', $model);

        $this->_initAction();
        $this->_view->getLayout()
            ->getBlock('example_rule_edit')
            ->setData('action', $this->getUrl('vendor_rules/*/save'));

        $this->_addBreadcrumb($id ? __('Edit Rule') : __('New Rule'), $id ? __('Edit Rule') : __('New Rule'));

        $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(
            $model->getRuleId() ? $model->getName() : __('New Rule')
        );
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

This is how to add new conditions:

> app/code/Vendor/Rules/Controller/Adminhtml/Example/Rule/NewConditionHtml.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Rules\Controller\Adminhtml\Example\Rule;

class NewConditionHtml extends \Vendor\Rules\Controller\Adminhtml\Example\Rule
{
    /**
     * New condition html action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $typeArr = explode('|', str_replace('-', '/', $this->getRequest()->getParam('type')));
        $type = $typeArr[0];

        $model = $this->_objectManager->create(
            $type
        )->setId(
            $id
        )->setType(
            $type
        )->setRule(
            $this->ruleFactory->create()
        )->setPrefix(
            'conditions'
        );
        if (!empty($typeArr[1])) {
            $model->setAttribute($typeArr[1]);
        }

        if ($model instanceof \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition) {
            $model->setJsFormObject($this->getRequest()->getParam('form'));
            $html = $model->asHtmlRecursive();
        } else {
            $html = '';
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($html);
    }
}
```

This class is responsible for loading the conditions that have been chosen in the interface (all the conditions can't be loaded at once).

....

Next, we need to create all the required blocks and layout.

Now, let's get down to creating and editing new rules. Let's create the main container block for editing:

> app/code/Vendor/Rules/Block/Adminhtml/Example/Rule/Edit.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Rules\Block\Adminhtml\Example\Rule;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize form
     * Add standard buttons
     * Add "Save and Continue" button
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_example_rule';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Vendor_Rules';

        parent::_construct();

        $this->buttonList->add(
            'save_and_continue_edit',
            [
                'class' => 'save',
                'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit', 'target' => '#edit_form']],
                ]
            ],
            10
        );
    }

    /**
     * Getter for form header text
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        $rule = $this->coreRegistry->registry('current_rule');
        if ($rule->getRuleId()) {
            return __("Edit Rule '%1'", $this->escapeHtml($rule->getName()));
        } else {
            return __('New Rule');
        }
    }

}
```

When done, we should add the controllers title and the `save` and `edit current model` buttons in the Constructor. Also, here you should add the main text for of the block.

This is a form itself:

> app/code/Vendor/Rules/Block/Adminhtml/Example/Rule/Edit/Form.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Rules\Block\Adminhtml\Example\Rule\Edit;

class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('example_rule_form');
        $this->setTitle(__('Rule Information'));
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form before rendering HTML
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                    'action' => $this->getUrl('vendor_rules/example_rule/save'),
                    'method' => 'post',
                ],
            ]
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

and tabs:

> app/code/Vendor/Rules/Block/Adminhtml/Example/Rule/Edit/Tabs.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Rules\Block\Adminhtml\Example\Rule\Edit;

class Tabs extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('rules_edit_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(__('Rules'));
    }
}
```

We'll have the two tabs: Ceneral model's information and Conditions.

> app/code/Vendor/Rules/Block/Adminhtml/Example/Rule/Edit/Tab/Main.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Rules\Block\Adminhtml\Example\Rule\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Main extends Generic implements TabInterface
{

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Rule Information');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Rule Information');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form before rendering HTML
     *
     * @return Generic
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_rule');

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('General Information')]);

        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('rule_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'rule_id']);
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'name',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'name', 'label' => __('Rule Name'), 'title' => __('Rule Name'), 'required' => true]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'description',
            'textarea',
            [
                'name' => 'description',
                'label' => __('Description'),
                'title' => __('Description'),
                'style' => 'height: 100px;'
            ]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'is_active',
            'select',
            [
                'label' => __('Status'),
                'title' => __('Status'),
                'name' => 'is_active',
                'required' => true,
                'options' => ['1' => __('Active'), '0' => __('Inactive')]
            ]
        );

        if (!$model->getId()) {
            $model->setData('is_active', '1');
        }

        $fieldset->addField('sort_order', 'text', ['name' => 'sort_order', 'label' => __('Priority')]);

        $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
        $fieldset->addField(
            'from_date',
            'date',
            [
                'name' => 'from_date',
                'label' => __('From'),
                'title' => __('From'),
                'input_format' => \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
                'date_format' => $dateFormat
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'to_date',
            'date',
            [
                'name' => 'to_date',
                'label' => __('To'),
                'title' => __('To'),
                'input_format' => \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
                'date_format' => $dateFormat
            ]
        );

        $form->setValues($model->getData());

        if ($model->isReadonly()) {
            foreach ($fieldset->getElements() as $element) {
                $element->setReadonly(true, true);
            }
        }

        $this->setForm($form);

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('adminhtml_example_rule_edit_tab_main_prepare_form', ['form' => $form]);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Conditions:

> app/code/Vendor/Rules/Block/Adminhtml/Example/Rule/Edit/Tab/Conditions.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Rules\Block\Adminhtml\Example\Rule\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;

class Conditions extends Generic implements TabInterface
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset
     */
    protected $rendererFieldset;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions
     */
    protected $conditions;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
        $this->conditions = $conditions;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form before rendering HTML
     *
     * @return Generic
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_rule');

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');

        $renderer = $this->rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
            'Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml'
        )->setNewChildUrl(
            $this->getUrl('vendor_rules/example_rule/newConditionHtml/form/rule_conditions_fieldset')
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'conditions_fieldset',
            [
                'legend' => __(
                    'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
                )
            ]
        )->setRenderer(
            $renderer
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'conditions',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'conditions', 'label' => __('Conditions'), 'title' => __('Conditions')]
        )->setRule(
            $model
        )->setRenderer(
            $this->conditions
        );

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

To view more details, please [follow this link](http://blog.mageworx.com/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/).

Comment: Hello MageWorx, Your code help for me but data are not save in database.
Can you tell what i do for that?

Comment: @PayalPatel we've answered your question in your topic.

Comment: could you help on this ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190537/magento-2-sales-rules-in-custom-ui-form-is-empty-on-editing

Comment: this worked like charm, though I updated changed Sales rule to Catalog rules . now I want to add some certain conditions in drop down from my custom table. How can I define them?

Comment: How we can achieve Catalog Price Rule instead of Cart Price Rule

Comment: @MageWorx Thank you so much for this help, it would be great if you let us know how we can apply those condition in the frontend?

Answer (score 4):

Using UI component for Magento2.1

```
<fieldset name="conditions">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Conditions</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <container name="conditions_apply_to" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Magento\SalesRule\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Edit\Tab\Conditions</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I can save values as serialized array in db. But how do I retrieve it back?

Comment: i can save in db, but i cannot find on edit in form.field is empty in edit form. could you help? 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190537/magento-2-sales-rules-in-custom-ui-form-is-empty-on-editing

Comment: this is showing for sales, How we can get only for category?

Comment: Can we get catalog price rule conditions instead of cart price rule?

Comment: @Sohel Rana sir how to add a custom fieldset in sales rule form in admin like this https://prnt.sc/oqiac8

Answer (score 0):

> Follow Below Steps:

**Step-1:** Create **registration.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendoreName_AddConditionFiled',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step-2:** Create **module.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
           <module name="Magento_Checkout"></module>
           <module name="Magento_Catalog"></module>
       </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step-3:** Create **InstallSchema.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Setup**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if (!$installer->tableExists('VendoreName_custom_condition')) {
            $tableName = $installer->getTable('VendoreName_custom_condition');
            $table = $installer->getConnection()
                ->newTable($tableName)
                ->addColumn(
                    'rule_id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    10,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary' => true,
                    ],
                    'Rule ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'rule_status',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'default' => null,
                    ],
                    'Rule Status'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'rule_name',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    [
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'default' => null,
                    ],
                    'Rule Name'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'conditions_serialized',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    '2M',
                    [],
                    'Conditions Serialized'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'actions_serialized',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    '2M',
                    [],
                    'Actions Serialized'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'create_date',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    null,
                    [
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT,
                    ],
                    'Create Date Time'
                )
                ->setComment('VendoreName Demo For Condition Field')
                ->setOption('type', 'InnoDB')
                ->setOption('charset', 'utf8');
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Here conditions_serialized and actions_serialized are used to store condition field value. So you must be add into you table. After creating table we add resource model and collection. Our Model name is CustomCondition.

**Step-4:** Create **CustomCondition.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Model**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model;

use VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition as CustomConditionResourceModel;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel;

class CustomCondition extends AbstractModel
{
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'VendoreName_addconditionfiled';
    protected $_eventObject = 'rule';
    protected $condCombineFactory;
    protected $condProdCombineF;
    protected $validatedAddresses = [];
    protected $_selectProductIds;
    protected $_displayProductIds;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->condCombineFactory = $condCombineFactory;
        $this->condProdCombineF = $condProdCombineF;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $localeDate, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init(CustomConditionResourceModel::class);
        $this->setIdFieldName('rule_id');
    }

    public function getConditionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condCombineFactory->create();
    }

    public function getActionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condCombineFactory->create();
    }

    public function hasIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? true : false;
    }

    public function setIsValidForAddress($address, $validationResult)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] = $validationResult;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] : false;
    }

    private function _getAddressId($address)
    {
        if ($address instanceof Address) {
            return $address->getId();
        }
        return $address;
    }

    public function getConditionsFieldSetId($formName = '')
    {
        return $formName . 'rule_conditions_fieldset_' . $this->getId();
    }

    public function getActionFieldSetId($formName = '')
    {
        return $formName . 'rule_actions_fieldset_' . $this->getId();
    }

    public function getMatchProductIds()
    {
        $productCollection = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection'
        );
        $productFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory'
        );
        $this->_selectProductIds = [];
        $this->setCollectedAttributes([]);
        $this->getConditions()->collectValidatedAttributes($productCollection);
        \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator'
        )->walk(
            $productCollection->getSelect(),
            [[$this, 'callbackValidateProductCondition']],
            [
                'attributes' => $this->getCollectedAttributes(),
                'product' => $productFactory->create(),
            ]
        );
        return $this->_selectProductIds;
    }

    public function callbackValidateProductCondition($args)
    {
        $product = clone $args['product'];
        $product->setData($args['row']);
        $websites = $this->_getWebsitesMap();
        foreach ($websites as $websiteId => $defaultStoreId) {
            $product->setStoreId($defaultStoreId);
            if ($this->getConditions()->validate($product)) {
                $this->_selectProductIds[] = $product->getId();
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _getWebsitesMap()
    {
        $map = [];
        $websites = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'
        )->getWebsites();
        foreach ($websites as $website) {
            if ($website->getDefaultStore() === null) {
                continue;
            }
            $map[$website->getId()] = $website->getDefaultStore()->getId();
        }
        return $map;
    }
}
```

**Step-5:** Create **CustomCondition.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Model/ResourceModel**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class CustomCondition extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('VendoreName_custom_condition', 'rule_id');
    }
}
```

**Step-6:** Create **Collection.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Model/ResourceModel/CustomCondition**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition;

use VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\CustomCondition as CustomConditionModel;
use VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition as CustomConditionResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            CustomConditionModel::class,
            CustomConditionResourceModel::class
        );
    }
}
```

**Step-7:** Create **Collection.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Model/ResourceModel/CustomCondition/Grid**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition\Grid;

use VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition\Collection as CustomConditionCollection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document as CustomConditionModel;

class Collection extends CustomConditionCollection implements \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface
{
    protected $aggregations;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = CustomConditionModel::class,
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }

    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }

    public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }

    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Step-8:** Create **di.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <virtualType name="VendoreNameAddConditionFiledFilterPool"
                 type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="VendoreNameAddConditionFiledFilterPool"
                 type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">VendoreNameAddConditionFiledFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_custom_condition</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_custom_condition_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_custom_condition_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_condition_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>

    </type>
</config>
```

**Step-9:** Create **routes.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/etc/adminhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="addconditionfiled" frontName="addconditionfiled">
            <module name="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Step-10:** Create **Index.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Controller/Adminhtml/Index**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Add Rules'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**Step-11:** Create **menu.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/etc/adminhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
   <menu>
        <add id="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled::VendoreName_addconditionfiled"
             title="VendoreName - Add Condition Field"
             translate="title"
             module="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled"
             sortOrder="10"
             parent="Magento_Backend::marketing"
             resource="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled::VendoreName_addconditionfiled" />

        <add id="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled::menu"
             title="Add Rules"
             module="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled"
             sortOrder="100"
             parent="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled::VendoreName_addconditionfiled"
             action="addconditionfiled/index/index"
             resource="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled::menu"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

[Click Here For Part 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344612/82670)

[Click Here For Part 3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344613/82670)

**[Check condition with products in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344617/82670)**