# Magento 2.1 :- Add Conditions Rule in custom form

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to add condition action in my custom module admin form.

I use like below code all are working perfect, i got also all data in var_dump with save action, but data are not save in database.

I use also [follow this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132862/magento-add-condition-rule-in-a-custom-form-in-magento-2) and [this link](http://blog.mageworx.com/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/) but i can't data `save in database`.

Please suggest me what i can do now for data save.

> **app/code/Vendor/Rules/Block/Adminhtml/Rule/Edit/Tab/Conditions.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Rules\Block\Adminhtml\Rule\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Conditions extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements
    \Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabInterface
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset
     */
    protected $_rendererFieldset;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions
     */
    protected $_conditions;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory
     */
    private $ruleFactory;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
        $this->_conditions = $conditions;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * The getter function to get the new RuleFactory dependency
     *
     * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory
     *
     * @deprecated
     */
    private function getRuleFactory()
    {
        if ($this->ruleFactory === null) {
            $this->ruleFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory');
        }
        return $this->ruleFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function isAjaxLoaded()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RegistryConstants::CURRENT_SALES_RULE');

        if (!$model) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id');
            $model = $this->getRuleFactory()->create();
            $model->load($id);
        }
        $formName = 'sales_rule_form';
        $conditionsFieldSetId = $model->getConditionsFieldSetId($formName);

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');

        $renderer = $this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
            'Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml'
        )->setNewChildUrl(
            $this->getUrl('sales_rule/promo_quote/newConditionHtml/form/')
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'conditions_fieldset',
            [
                'legend' => __(
                    'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
                )
            ]
        )->setRenderer(
            $renderer
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'conditions',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'conditions', 'label' => __('Conditions'), 'title' => __('Conditions')]
        )->setRule(
            $model
        )->setRenderer(
            $this->_conditions
        );

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}

?>
```

> **app/code/Vendor/Rules/Setup/InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Rules\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
        $installer->getTable('rule_conditions')
        )->addColumn(
            'cond_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Condition ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'rule_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            32,
            [],
            'Shipping Restriction Id (Rule Id)'
        )->addColumn(
            'coupon_code',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Coupon Code'
        )->addColumn(
            'shopping_cart_rule',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Shopping Cart Rule'
        );

        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}

?>
```

> **app/code/Vendor/Rules/Model/Conditions.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Rules\Model;

class Conditions extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */

    const STATUS_ENABLED = 1;

    const STATUS_DISABLED = 0;

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Rules\Model\ResourceModel\Conditions');
    }

    public function getAvailableStatuses()
    {
        return [self::STATUS_ENABLED => __('Enabled'), self::STATUS_DISABLED => __('Disabled')];
    }

}

?>
```

> **app/code/Vendor/Rules/Model/ResourceModel/Conditions.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Rules\Model\ResourceModel;

class Conditions extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{   
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
        $connectionName = null
    ) {  
        parent::__construct($context, $connectionName);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('rule_conditions', 'cond_id');
    }   
}
?>
```

> **app/code/Vendor/Rules/Model/ResourceModel/Conditions/Collection.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Rules\Model\ResourceModel\Conditions;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'cond_id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Rules\Model\Conditions', 'Vendor\Rules\Model\ResourceModel\Conditions');
        $this->_map['fields']['cond_id'] = 'main_table.cond_id';
    }

    public function getAvailableStatuses()
    {
        return [self::STATUS_ENABLED => __('Enabled'), self::STATUS_DISABLED => __('Disabled')];
    }
}
?>
```

> **app/code/Vendor/Rules/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Save.php**

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Rules\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Vendor\Rules\Model\ConditionsFactory;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $ConditionsFactory;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param PostDataProcessor $dataProcessor
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        ConditionsFactory $ConditionsFactory,
        )
    {
        $this->ConditionsFactory = $ConditionsFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_Rules::rules_save');
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
         /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        if ($data) {

            /*----Rules-Model----*/
            $Condmodel = $this->ConditionsFactory->create();
            //var_dump($data['rule']['conditions']);exit; i got all data here, but data don't save in database

            if (isset($data['rule']['conditions'])) {
                $data['conditions'] = $data['rule']['conditions'];
            }
            if (isset($data['rule']['actions'])) {
                $data['actions'] = $data['rule']['actions'];
            }
            unset($data['rule']);

            $Condmodel->setData($data['rule']['conditions'])
                      ->setRuleId($data['rule_id'])
                      ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('cond_id'));

            try {

                $Condmodel->save();

                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Rules was successfully saved'));
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);

                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['rule_id' => $Condmodel->getId(), '_current' => true]);
                }

                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;

            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __($e->getMessage().'Something went wrong while saving the page.'));
            }

            $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['rule_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}

?>
```

> 1. Below my admin image this is perfect but data can't save in database and also don't get collection.

[image]

> 2. Below my `var_dump` data with save action in image

[image]

Any one know tell me please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a serious error in the controller's code:

```
if (isset($data['rule']['conditions'])) {
    $data['conditions'] = $data['rule']['conditions'];
}
if (isset($data['rule']['actions'])) {
    $data['actions'] = $data['rule']['actions'];
}
unset($data['rule']);

$Condmodel->setData($data['rule']['conditions'])
    ->setRuleId($data['rule_id'])
    ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('cond_id'));
```

You are trying to delete `$data['rule']` and then to transmit the data to the `$Condmodel->setData($data['rule']['conditions'])` model.

Try to modify this part of the code the following way:

```
$Condmodel->addData($data)->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('cond_id'));
```

Also, you have an error in the models. They should expand the default rule models and not an abstract ones.

You need to replace in the `app/code/Vendor/Rules/Model/Conditions.php` file:

```
class Conditions extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
```

by:

```
class Conditions extends \Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel
```

In the `app/code/Vendor/Rules/Model/ResourceModel/Conditions.php` file:

```
class Conditions extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
```

by:

```
class Conditions extends \Magento\Rule\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource
```

And in the `app/code/Vendor/Rules/Model/ResourceModel/Conditions/Collection.php` file:

```
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
```

by:

```
class Collection extends \Magento\Rule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection\AbstractCollection
```

Then, you need to check what is missing in your classes from these abstract classes and add it.

Comment: let me know how we can apply our created condition in the frontend