# How to add sales rule action fieldset in customer group area

Tags: magento2.3, fieldsets, sales-rule

I want to add sales rule fieldset to customer group form using custom module.

can any one please guide me on this how to add this sales rule condition form under customer group edit form and save this info in custom table for later use on frontend.

Here is how i would like to display in customer group form.

[image]

Problem is that sales rule is build using `uicomponent` and customer group form is build using `generic` class extended with `\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic`
So how can we add `uicomponent` in `generic` form

Also how to validate this condition on frontend please.

Comment: SalesRules  already has  customer group selection , Then why you want to add again?

Comment: @AmitBera Yes true but we need some more dependency based on that rule on customer group form that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the full customer group form file `Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form` with Rule fieldset.

You should override this to your custom module and change according to your need.

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

/**
 * Adminhtml customer groups edit form
 */
class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset
     */
    protected $_rendererFieldset;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions
     */
    protected $_conditions;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory
     */
    private $ruleFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxClass\Source\Customer
     */
    protected $_taxCustomer;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_taxHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $_groupRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $groupDataFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxClass\Source\Customer $taxCustomer
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxHelper
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterfaceFactory $groupDataFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxClass\Source\Customer $taxCustomer,
        \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxHelper,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterfaceFactory $groupDataFactory,
        \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_taxCustomer = $taxCustomer;
        $this->_taxHelper = $taxHelper;
        $this->_groupRepository = $groupRepository;
        $this->groupDataFactory = $groupDataFactory;
        $this->_rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
        $this->_conditions = $conditions;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form for render
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function getRuleFactory()
    {
        if ($this->ruleFactory === null) {
            $this->ruleFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory');
        }
        return $this->ruleFactory;
    }
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();

        $groupId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry(RegistryConstants::CURRENT_GROUP_ID);
        /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface $customerGroup */
        if ($groupId === null) {
            $customerGroup = $this->groupDataFactory->create();
            $defaultCustomerTaxClass = $this->_taxHelper->getDefaultCustomerTaxClass();
        } else {
            $customerGroup = $this->_groupRepository->getById($groupId);
            $defaultCustomerTaxClass = $customerGroup->getTaxClassId();
        }

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Group Information')]);

        $validateClass = sprintf(
            'required-entry validate-length maximum-length-%d',
            \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupManagement::GROUP_CODE_MAX_LENGTH
        );
        $name = $fieldset->addField(
            'customer_group_code',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'code',
                'label' => __('Group Name'),
                'title' => __('Group Name'),
                'note' => __(
                    'Maximum length must be less then %1 characters.',
                    \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupManagement::GROUP_CODE_MAX_LENGTH
                ),
                'class' => $validateClass,
                'required' => true
            ]
        );

        if ($customerGroup->getId() == 0 && $customerGroup->getCode()) {
            $name->setDisabled(true);
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'tax_class_id',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'tax_class',
                'label' => __('Tax Class'),
                'title' => __('Tax Class'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'values' => $this->_taxCustomer->toOptionArray(),
            ]
        );

        if ($customerGroup->getId() !== null) {
            // If edit add id
            $form->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id', 'value' => $customerGroup->getId()]);
        }

        if ($this->_backendSession->getCustomerGroupData()) {
            $form->addValues($this->_backendSession->getCustomerGroupData());
            $this->_backendSession->setCustomerGroupData(null);
        } else {
            // TODO: need to figure out how the DATA can work with forms
            $form->addValues(
                [
                    'id' => $customerGroup->getId(),
                    'customer_group_code' => $customerGroup->getCode(),
                    'tax_class_id' => $defaultCustomerTaxClass,
                ]
            );
        }

        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RegistryConstants::CURRENT_SALES_RULE');

        if (!$model) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id');
            $model = $this->getRuleFactory()->create();
            $model->load($id);
        }
        $formName = 'sales_rule_form';
        $conditionsFieldSetId = $model->getConditionsFieldSetId($formName);
        $newChildUrl = $this->getUrl(
            'sales_rule/promo_quote/newConditionHtml/form/' . $conditionsFieldSetId,
            ['form_namespace' => $formName]
        );
         $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');

        $renderer = $this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
            'Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml'
        )->setNewChildUrl($newChildUrl)->setFieldSetId(
            $conditionsFieldSetId
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'conditions_fieldset',
            [
                'legend' => __(
                    'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
                )
            ]
        )->setRenderer(
            $renderer
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'conditions',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'conditions', 'label' => __('Conditions'), 'title' => __('Conditions')]
        )->setRule(
            $model
        )->setRenderer(
            $this->_conditions
        );

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $form->setId('edit_form');
        $form->setAction($this->getUrl('customer/*/save'));
        $form->setMethod('post');
        $this->setForm($form);
    }
}
```

It will add the condition block inside your customer group add/edit form.

For more details [Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139700/magento-2-1-add-conditions-rule-in-custom-form)