# Magento 2 Ui Conditions component in custom module

Tags: magento-2.1, module, ui-library

Please tell me about using Ui Conditions component in my custom module. I`m trying to make module with products conditions filtration, like a catalog widget 'catalog product list':

[image: conditions filtration]

I'm trying to implement conditions component in XML like this:

```
<fieldset name="conditions">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Conditions</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <container name="conditions_apply_to" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Magento\SalesRule\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Edit\Tab\Conditions</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```

And then I have this view in admin console:

[image]

But it have wrong menu when i trying to add new condition. I have:

[image]

I need to (like a catalog product list widget):

[image]

Questions:

1. The right way to implement and use conditions component;
2. How to take right menu when I add new condition;
3. How to take a view of the conditions component like catalog product list widget, instead view which I have.

Thanks beforehand!

---

For the first and third questions, I found the answer here:

[Magento Add Condition Rule In A Custom Form in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132862/magento-add-condition-rule-in-a-custom-form-in-magento-2)

But cannot understand, how to take right menu, with product attributes instead cart attributes. Please help anyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second question.

Full example: [here](http://blog.mageworx.com/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/)

In this example you need replace follow lines in file app/code/Vendor/Rules/Model/Rule.php

find this:

```
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
```

Replasce with:

```
\Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
\Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition\ProductFactory $condProdCombineF,
```