# Magento 2 Add Condition Rule In A Custom UI Form

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-rules, magento2.3.6

Im using Magento 2.3.6. I want to add condition action in my custom module admin form.
I use like below code but I have not received condition in var_dump with save action.

Please suggest me what i can do now.

> **app/code/Bss/LensSystem/Block/Adminhtml/Discount/Edit/Tab/Conditions.php**

```
<?php

namespace Bss\LensSystem\Block\Adminhtml\Discount\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Conditions extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset
     */
    protected $_rendererFieldset;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions
     */
    protected $_conditions;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_nameInLayout = 'conditions_serialized';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory
     */
    private $ruleFactory;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
        $this->_conditions = $conditions;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * The getter function to get the new RuleFactory dependency
     *
     * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory
     *
     * @deprecated
     */
    private function getRuleFactory()
    {
        if ($this->ruleFactory === null) {
            $this->ruleFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory');
        }
        return $this->ruleFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function isAjaxLoaded()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form before rendering HTML
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RegistryConstants::CURRENT_SALES_RULE);
        $form = $this->addTabToForm($model);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    /**
     * Handles addition of conditions tab to supplied form.
     *
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $model
     * @param string $fieldsetId
     * @param string $formName
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Form
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function addTabToForm($model, $fieldsetId = 'conditions_serialized', $formName = 'addlabel_form')
    {
        if (!$model) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $model = $this->getRuleFactory()->create();
            $model->load($id);
        }
        $conditionsFieldSetId = $model->getConditionsFieldSetId($formName);
        $newChildUrl = $this->getUrl(
            'sales_rule/promo_quote/newConditionHtml/form/' . $conditionsFieldSetId,
            ['form_namespace' => $formName]
        );

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');
        $renderer = $this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
            'Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml'
        )->setNewChildUrl(
            $newChildUrl
        )->setFieldSetId(
            $conditionsFieldSetId
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            $fieldsetId,
            [
                'legend' => __(
                    'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
                )
            ]
        )->setRenderer(
            $renderer
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'conditions',
            'text',
            [
                'name'           => 'conditions',
                'label'          => __('Conditions'),
                'title'          => __('Conditions'),
                'required'       => true,
                'data-form-part' => $formName
            ]
        )->setRule(
            $model
        )->setRenderer(
            $this->_conditions
        );

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setConditionFormName($model->getConditions(), $formName);
        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Handles addition of form name to condition and its conditions.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition $conditions
     * @param string $formName
     * @return void
     */
    private function setConditionFormName(\Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition $conditions, $formName)
    {
        $conditions->setFormName($formName);
        if ($conditions->getConditions() && is_array($conditions->getConditions())) {
            foreach ($conditions->getConditions() as $condition) {
                $this->setConditionFormName($condition, $formName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **app/code/Bss/LensSystem/view/adminhtml/ui_component/lenssystem_rules_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">lenssystem_rules_form.lenssystem_rules_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">lenssystem_rules_form.lenssystem_rules_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Lens Fitting Height Form</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Bss\LensSystem\Block\Adminhtml\Options\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">Bss\LensSystem\Block\Adminhtml\Options\Edit\ResetButton</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Bss\LensSystem\Block\Adminhtml\Options\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Bss\LensSystem\Block\Adminhtml\Options\Edit\SaveButton</item>
            <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">Bss\LensSystem\Block\Adminhtml\Options\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="lenssystem_rules_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Bss\LensSystem\Model\RuleDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">lenssystem_rules_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">rule_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">rule_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/save"/>
                    <item name="validate_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/validate"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="main_fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Rule Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Description</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">description</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">description</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset name="conditions_serialized">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Conditions</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="conditions_serialized" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Bss\LensSystem\Block\Adminhtml\Discount\Edit\Tab\Conditions</argument>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> **app/code/Bss/LensSystem/Controller/Adminhtml/Discount/Save.php**

```
public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

        var_dump($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());die;
    }
```

> **Admin Form**

[image]

> **Result when var_dump with save action**

[image]

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344614/82670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like your form part is not correct.

Can you change form part same as ui_component name?

`'data-form-part'`

Comment: I have fixed this problem. Thanks you!

Comment: Could you please post how did you fixed it ?